# Publisher service stops-waiting for publishing

Tags: 2011, publishing, 2011-sp1

We are getting waiting for publishing in Tridion and when we checked our publisher services found that it stopped automatically. Below error is reported in event viewer.

```
Faulting application name: TcmPublisher_x86.exe, version: 6.1.0.996, time stamp: 0x4eb0f691
Faulting module name: clr.dll, version: 4.0.30319.1008, time stamp: 0x517a1be7
Exception code: 0xc00000fd
Fault offset: 0x00357df5
Faulting process id: 0x8f8
Faulting application start time: 0x01cef4d29f54fc3b
Faulting application path: c:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\TcmPublisher_x86.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Report Id: 74c8a990-60c6-11e3-a019-ecbd5291bc16
```

Has anyone came across similar error. We have checked for the `Faulting module path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll` and found this URL as fix on .NET v4 http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2640103.

Can anyone suggest an alternate solution.

Version of SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.
Windows server 2008 R2

This is not a fresh install of Tridion. It had been working with no issues but above behaviour started two days before.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and give some more detail on your setup, what version of SDL Tridion & OS are you using, is it a fresh install or has the problem occurred after a certain update or action etc.?

Comment: @BartKoopman I have updated the question with details.

Comment: When you start the Publisher service again, does it work, or does it stop with the same error again? I have personally never seen that error again, so you might want to contact Customer Support about it.

Comment: We have started the services and this happen again. Almost 14 times this is reported today in event log.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try running the publisher in Debug mode and see if that solves your issue.

You can do this by stopping the publishing service and then opening a command prompt on the server and typing

```
"%TRIDION_HOME%\bin\TcmPublisher" /debug > C:\logs\publisher.log
```

Try your operation again and then have a look at the C:\logs\publisher.log file to see what is going on.

Comment: We have rebooted the server and no issue reported henceforth .We are keeping the service in debug mode and will check the logs.